# Calculating min number that satisfies a comparison using recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to calculate the minimum "n" that satisfies the following expression: (n+a)^k < m^n = n where a,k,m are 3 Integers in Haskell. So far I have done this but it seems to be incorect. What am I doing wrong?

```
search a k m
|(n+a)^k < m^n = n
where 
    n = count 1
        where
            count :: Integer -> Integer
            count 1000000 = 1000000
            count n = count (n+1)
```

My train of thought is that count will increase by one each time, and the expression will be checked, but apparently it goes all the way up to 1000000 (which is just a roof value)

Comment: There seem to be some fundamental misconceptions here. It is important to realize that `count` is just a function of a variable that happens to be called `n` (this is unrelated to the other `n`). As written here, it just calls itself with its argument+1, until it reaches `1000000`. So, `count x`, for any value `x` less than or equal to `1000000`, will just equal `1000000`.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yes I understand that, I see why it is wrong, but I dont see how to "fix" that, I cant think of a way to implement this problem

Comment: Do you mean the minumum `n` that satisfies the inequality `(n+a)^k < m^n` (for some given integers `a`,`k` and `m`)? Your expression above says `(n+a)^k < m^n = n`

Answer (score 2):

I would write is slightly different

```
search a k m = go 1
      where go 10000 = 10000
            go n     = if ((n+a)^k < m^n) then n else go (n+1)
```

testing with

```
search 2 3 4
```

returns

```
4
```

Comment: Suggest that it is worth noting that if there are no `n` (in the range 1 .. 10000) that satisfy `(n+a)^k < m^n` then this function will return 10000.

Comment: yes it's given as the roof value in the question.  I think I dropped couple zeros...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `filter` and `minimum` combinators from `Data.List` like so:

```
import Data.List

search :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
search a k m =
  minimum $ filter (\n -> (n+a)^k < m^n) [1 .. 1000000]
  -- filter picks out the n that satisfy the inequality and minimum gives you the minimum
```

---- Update based on comments received:

The problem with `search` as defined above is that it will throw an exception if there are no solutions in the range `1 .. 1000000`.
A safer way of writing search (i.e without throwing exceptions) would be to use `Maybe` to encode the possibility of there being no solutions in the given range. Something like:

```
safeSearch :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
safeSearch a k m roof =
  let
    solutions = filter (\n -> (n+a)^k < m^n) [1 .. roof]
  in
    case solutions of 
      [] -> Nothing
      _  -> Just $ head solutions
```

Comment: That's nice and clear, though since we're testing in sequence, `head` will work just as well as `minimum` (and faster).

Comment: @luqui fair enough although in general, head is unsafe - if the filter yields an empty list, head will throw an exception.

Comment: @novemberkilo `minimum []` is equivalent to `head []` -- both raise an exception.

Comment: The explicit import of `Data.List` isn't necessary.